# Get the IP from the list and ping using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have scenario where I have below details in log.ini file

```
Hostname    : DLC1MQF
IP Address   : 10.210.208.102
Temporary IP : 10.212.215.91
Subnet Mask  : 255.255.248.0
Gateway      : 10.212.208.1
```

what I am trying to do is only get the Gateway information from the log.ini and ping the same and see if pinging or not. If not I have to write a condition. So how I can write that ?

I am able to write something like this, but I have problem trimming the gateway.txt output

```
$log = Get-Content C:\Windows\ImageLog.ini
foreach ($line in $log) {
if ($line -like "*Gateway*") {
$line | out-file -FilePath "C:\Windows\Gateway.txt"
}
}
```

Comment: You're close.  `If (...) { ping (($line -replace '.*:').Trim())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$log = Get-Content C:\Windows\ImageLog.ini
$gateways = $log -like "*Gateway*"
foreach ($g in $gateways) {
    $ip = ($g -split ':')[1].Trim()
    ping $ip
    if (!$?) {
        $ip | Out-File -FilePath C:\Windows\Gateway.txt -Append
    }
}
```

`$log -like "*Gateway*"` extracts Gateway lines.

`($g -split ':')[0]` is "Gateway"

`($g -split ':')[1]` is "10.212.208.1"

`Trim()` is the trimming method of `System.String`

`$?` contains the result of `ping`. For more information, see [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)

If you would like to suppress the output of `ping`, run `ping $ip > $null`

If you would like to overwrite Gateway.txt, remove `-Append` switch parameter from `Out-File` cmdlet.